# Migrate HANA to MPP

Tags: hadoop, hana, migrate, vora

We have multiple information views (calculated/Analytics/attribute) views in HANA, we are planning to migrate our datawarehouse from HANA to other big data vendors.

Is there a way to convert calc views from the backend metadata to some python/sql or any JS scripts?

Answer (score 0):

The SAP HANA information views (attribute, analytic and calculation views) are specific to SAP HANA and contain proprietary functionality (e.g. hierarchy processing, unit/currency conversion, language dependent text-joins) that are not available on other platforms.

These views are not built from common SQL-based elements but are specific to SAP HANA. While you can export the definition of the views easily via SAP HANA Studio, all there is stored in the XML definition that has no meaning on another platform.

All in all the answer to the question is "No" - there is no automatic conversion available/possible.